# What is the difference between "image/png" and "image/x-png"?

Tags: language-agnostic, mime-types

What is the difference between "image/png" and "image/x-png"?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The `x-` prefix is given to non-standard MIME types (i. e. not registered with IANA). So I assume that `image/x-png` would have been PNG before the MIME type was standardized.

> **6.3. New Content-Transfer-Encodings**

> Implementors may, if necessary, define private Content-Transfer-Encoding values, but must use an x-token, which is a name prefixed by “`X-`”, to indicate its non-standard status, e. g., “`Content-Transfer-Encoding: x-my-new-encoding`”.  Additional standardized Content-Transfer-Encoding values must be specified by a standards-track RFC.
> The requirements such specifications must meet are given in [RFC 2048](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2048).
> As such, all content-transfer-encoding namespace except that
> beginning with “`X-`” is explicitly reserved to the IETF for future
> use.

> —[RFC 2045 — Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions, Section 6.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045#section-6.3)

This is also documented in the PNG specification. See [FalseVinylShrub's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086374/what-is-the-difference-between-image-png-and-image-x-png/2086413#2086413).

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it's more complete. But could you fold in FalseVinylShrub's info on IE so it's all in one place?

Comment: Hm, I found the info on IE less valuable than the PNG specification as a hard source.

Comment: Lol that's because you aren't trying to figure out why all the pngs are coming from the same company, but only one user is uploading them as X-Pngs:)

Comment: By the way, shouldn't you have linked to http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2046#section-6 as Content Transfer Encodings are not the same things as Media Types - the principle is clear, though ;-)

Answer (score 25):

According to http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#A-Media-type

> The internet media type "image/png" is the Internet Media Type for PNG [RFC-2045], [RFC-2048]. It is recommended that implementations also recognize the media type "image/x-png".

So, if you're delivering or uploading a PNG image, 'image/png' is the correct one to use. However, if you're accepting uploads or otherwise interpreting the media type, you are recommended to accept either.

By the way, I found a reference from 2008 that Internet Explorer (version unspecified) was uploading PNG images with a type of image/x-png, so this was a real issue for someone as recently as that.

Comment: I can confirm that IE is "x-png"ing them in IE8.

Answer (score 6):

According to [Wikipedia's article on Internet Media Types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type), and [the article it](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045#section-6.3) cites...

> Types or subtypes that begin with x-
> are nonstandard

So my guess is "image/x-png" is probably leftover from the days when png was pretty new, and as such, not standardized.

Comment: I prefer quoting the actual source, which, by the way, is linked directly after the quoted sentence :-)

Comment: Actually that's a citation, not a quote... the original RFC doesn't contain the words I quote ;) but I dig what you mean, and added a link thereto.

Answer (score 6):

image/x-png was the type before PNG was accepted by the IANA as an official mime type.

http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/image/

The official image/png MIME type for PNG, approved on 14 October 1996

http://www.w3.org/Graphics/PNG/