# MIME-type conventions, standards or limitations?

Tags: standards, mime, mime-types, conventions

Given a new, proprietary file format that cannot currently be handled by any known application, I assume you can just invent a new MIME type value as follows:

```
Content-Type: application/my-arbitrary-format
```

Assuming this is the way to go, are there any **limitations** (format, syntax, length, reserved words, or otherwise), **standards** (IETF, ISO, W3C, IEEE, etc), or **conventions** (like the slash `type/format`)?

*Note that I do NOT want to use a known MIME type value*, because the browser and/or OS should not make assumptions about what can or cannot open the file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To do this correctly, you can register your new type with IANA.
http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/

Comment: Is there a way to invent application specific MIME types that avoid the registration process? For example, if I was developing a RESTful API that needed a custom flavour of JSON (application/my-app-special1+json).

Comment: @LeaHayes, You can send whatever you want, essentially.  As for why you'd want to create something that was like JSON but not JSON, I'm not sure...

Comment: I was hoping that there would be a general purpose convention that could be used. I wanted to define a JSON schema that is used to transport JavaScript, CSS and dependencies for a custom module loader. I wanted to use a custom MIME to identify that the returned JSON data is to be automatically interpreted (whereas application/json would be treated purely as data). This way the module loader could be used via an API and consumers of the API (probably with my JavaScript library) would understand the nature of the response... It is just an idea that I am toying with. Cheers!

Comment: @LeaHayes, The Content-Type should identify the type of returned data, not what is done with it.  That is the convention.  Sure, you could change this, but generally if you are returning JSON, you should send it as such.  Of course, there are plenty of exceptions to this in use.  XHTML is one of them, as it is just XML but uses `application/xhtml+xml`.

Comment: @Lea: You probably want to use the prefix `x-` for non-standard values, see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086374/what-is-the-difference-between-image-png-and-image-x-png

Answer (score 16):

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type#Registration_trees) page gives conventions for naming MIME types. Here is the section about Custom MIME Types:

> - Use `x.` as prefix to the subtype for experimental MIME types.  Note that the `x-` prefix is also valid for this purpose, but is discouraged in favor of `x.` to promote symmetry with other prefixes.
> - Use `vnd.` as prefix to the subtypte for vendor specific MIME types which are part of a commercial product.  The `vnd.` prefix should be followed by the vendor name and subtype separated by a period (e.g.
>   `application/vnd.mozilla.xul+xml`).
> - Use `prs.` as prefix to the subtype for personal/vanity MIME types which aren't part of a commercial product.

Comment: Original link is broken completely, seems to have been missing for several years.

Comment: The Wikipedia page on media types has more or less the same info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type#Registration_trees

Comment: As far as I understood meaning `x.` from this wiki, if you are the vendor, but your format is not public yet b2b oriented, you can use `x.` instead of `vnd`.

Comment: Should custom MIME Types always be a subtype of `application/`?

Comment: According to the RFC, https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6838 :
   "...However, with the simplified registration procedures described above
   for vendor and personal trees, it should rarely, if ever, be
   necessary to use unregistered types.  Therefore, use of types in the
   "x." tree is strongly discouraged."