# How to get the content/type of a file at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, content-type

I am trying to determine dynamically the content/type of a input file. If I would be in a windows application I could write code like this ([from this blog](http://codeasp.net/blogs/raghav_khunger/microsoft-net/531/how-to-get-content-type-of-a-file-in-c))

```
private string GetContentType(string fileName) {
    string contentType = "application/octetstream";
    string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileName).ToLower();
    Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey registryKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(ext);
    if (registryKey != null && registryKey.GetValue("Content Type") != null)
        contentType = registryKey.GetValue("Content Type").ToString();
    return contentType;
}
```

What other methods are more suitable for an MVC application?

I would like to use the param within the `Controller.File(...)` method that receive a filepath and a contentype.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> **Important note:** This answer was written in 2011, a few years before [masterwok's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23373189/31532) was written. Whilst my answer is still *acceptable*, masterwok's answer is better and more concise. Use and upvote that answer instead. Everything below is for posterity.

I would just use the file extension rather than try to do something clever that may eventually come back to bite you in the arse. :)

The file extension doesn't need to be registered on your system (although I don't know exactly what you're doing with the file...). You could use something like an enum or db table which contains information on acceptable extensions if you want to filter out files.

Please see [@Tolgahan's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4577152/31532) on this. I created a C# enum below based on this which should provide people with a starting point should they wish to create a db/enum/xml-based approach to this.

```
Public enum MimeTypes
{
  [Description("application/postscript")]
  ai,
  [Description("audio/x-aiff")]
  aif,
  [Description("audio/x-aiff")]
  aifc,
  [Description("audio/x-aiff")]
  aiff,
  [Description("text/plain")]
  asc,
  [Description("application/atom+xml")]
  atom,
  [Description("audio/basic")]
  au,
  [Description("video/x-msvideo")]
  avi,
  [Description("application/x-bcpio")]
  bcpio,
  [Description("application/octet-stream")]
  bin,
  [Description("image/bmp")]
  bmp,
  [Description("application/x-netcdf")]
  cdf,
  [Description("image/cgm")]
  cgm,
  [Description("application/octet-stream")]
  class,
  [Description("application/x-cpio")]
  cpio,
  [Description("application/mac-compactpro")]
  cpt,
  [Description("application/x-csh")]
  csh,
  [Description("text/css")]
  css,
  [Description("application/x-director")]
  dcr,
  [Description("video/x-dv")]
  dif,
  [Description("application/x-director")]
  dir,
  [Description("image/vnd.djvu")]
  djv,
  [Description("image/vnd.djvu")]
  djvu,
  [Description("application/octet-stream")]
  dll,
  [Description("application/octet-stream")]
  dmg,
  [Description("application/octet-stream")]
  dms,
  [Description("application/msword")]
  doc,
  [Description("application/xml-dtd")]
  dtd,
  [Description("video/x-dv")]
  dv,
  [Description("application/x-dvi")]
  dvi,
  [Description("application/x-director")]
  dxr,
  [Description("application/postscript")]
  eps,
  [Description("text/x-setext")]
  etx,
  [Description("application/octet-stream")]
  exe,
  [Description("application/andrew-inset")]
  ez,
  [Description("image/gif")]
  gif,
  [Description("application/srgs")]
  gram,
  [Description("application/srgs+xml")]
  grxml,
  [Description("application/x-gtar")]
  gtar,
  [Description("application/x-hdf")]
  hdf,
  [Description("application/mac-binhex40")]
  hqx,
  [Description("text/html")]
  htm,
  [Description("text/html")]
  html,
  [Description("x-conference/x-cooltalk")]
  ice,
  [Description("image/x-icon")]
  ico,
  [Description("text/calendar")]
  ics,
  [Description("image/ief")]
  ief,
  [Description("text/calendar")]
  ifb,
  [Description("model/iges")]
  iges,
  [Description("model/iges")]
  igs,
  [Description("application/x-java-jnlp-file")]
  jnlp,
  [Description("image/jp2")]
  jp2,
  [Description("image/jpeg")]
  jpe,
  [Description("image/jpeg")]
  jpeg,
  [Description("image/jpeg")]
  jpg,
  [Description("application/x-javascript")]
  js,
  [Description("audio/midi")]
  kar,
  [Description("application/x-latex")]
  latex,
  [Description("application/octet-stream")]
  lha,
  [Description("application/octet-stream")]
  lzh,
  [Description("audio/x-mpegurl")]
  m3u,
  [Description("audio/mp4a-latm")]
  m4a,
  [Description("audio/mp4a-latm")]
  m4b,
  [Description("audio/mp4a-latm")]
  m4p,
  [Description("video/vnd.mpegurl")]
  m4u,
  [Description("video/x-m4v")]
  m4v,
  [Description("image/x-macpaint")]
  mac,
  [Description("application/x-troff-man")]
  man,
  [Description("application/mathml+xml")]
  mathml,
  [Description("application/x-troff-me")]
  me,
  [Description("model/mesh")]
  mesh,
  [Description("audio/midi")]
  mid,
  [Description("audio/midi")]
  midi,
  [Description("application/vnd.mif")]
  mif,
  [Description("video/quicktime")]
  mov,
  [Description("video/x-sgi-movie")]
  movie,
  [Description("audio/mpeg")]
  mp2,
  [Description("audio/mpeg")]
  mp3,
  [Description("video/mp4")]
  mp4,
  [Description("video/mpeg")]
  mpe,
  [Description("video/mpeg")]
  mpeg,
  [Description("video/mpeg")]
  mpg,
  [Description("audio/mpeg")]
  mpga,
  [Description("application/x-troff-ms")]
  ms,
  [Description("model/mesh")]
  msh,
  [Description("video/vnd.mpegurl")]
  mxu,
  [Description("application/x-netcdf")]
  nc,
  [Description("application/oda")]
  oda,
  [Description("application/ogg")]
  ogg,
  [Description("image/x-portable-bitmap")]
  pbm,
  [Description("image/pict")]
  pct,
  [Description("chemical/x-pdb")]
  pdb,
  [Description("application/pdf")]
  pdf,
  [Description("image/x-portable-graymap")]
  pgm,
  [Description("application/x-chess-pgn")]
  pgn,
  [Description("image/pict")]
  pic,
  [Description("image/pict")]
  pict,
  [Description("image/png")]
  png,
  [Description("image/x-portable-anymap")]
  pnm,
  [Description("image/x-macpaint")]
  pnt,
  [Description("image/x-macpaint")]
  pntg,
  [Description("image/x-portable-pixmap")]
  ppm,
  [Description("application/vnd.ms-powerpoint")]
  ppt,
  [Description("application/postscript")]
  ps,
  [Description("video/quicktime")]
  qt,
  [Description("image/x-quicktime")]
  qti,
  [Description("image/x-quicktime")]
  qtif,
  [Description("audio/x-pn-realaudio")]
  ra,
  [Description("audio/x-pn-realaudio")]
  ram,
  [Description("image/x-cmu-raster")]
  ras,
  [Description("application/rdf+xml")]
  rdf,
  [Description("image/x-rgb")]
  rgb,
  [Description("application/vnd.rn-realmedia")]
  rm,
  [Description("application/x-troff")]
  roff,
  [Description("text/rtf")]
  rtf,
  [Description("text/richtext")]
  rtx,
  [Description("text/sgml")]
  sgm,
  [Description("text/sgml")]
  sgml,
  [Description("application/x-sh")]
  sh,
  [Description("application/x-shar")]
  shar,
  [Description("model/mesh")]
  silo,
  [Description("application/x-stuffit")]
  sit,
  [Description("application/x-koan")]
  skd,
  [Description("application/x-koan")]
  skm,
  [Description("application/x-koan")]
  skp,
  [Description("application/x-koan")]
  skt,
  [Description("application/smil")]
  smi,
  [Description("application/smil")]
  smil,
  [Description("audio/basic")]
  snd,
  [Description("application/octet-stream")]
  so,
  [Description("application/x-futuresplash")]
  spl,
  [Description("application/x-wais-source")]
  src,
  [Description("application/x-sv4cpio")]
  sv4cpio,
  [Description("application/x-sv4crc")]
  sv4crc,
  [Description("image/svg+xml")]
  svg,
  [Description("application/x-shockwave-flash")]
  swf,
  [Description("application/x-troff")]
  t,
  [Description("application/x-tar")]
  tar,
  [Description("application/x-tcl")]
  tcl,
  [Description("application/x-tex")]
  tex,
  [Description("application/x-texinfo")]
  texi,
  [Description("application/x-texinfo")]
  texinfo,
  [Description("image/tiff")]
  tif,
  [Description("image/tiff")]
  tiff,
  [Description("application/x-troff")]
  tr,
  [Description("text/tab-separated-values")]
  tsv,
  [Description("text/plain")]
  txt,
  [Description("application/x-ustar")]
  ustar,
  [Description("application/x-cdlink")]
  vcd,
  [Description("model/vrml")]
  vrml,
  [Description("application/voicexml+xml")]
  vxml,
  [Description("audio/x-wav")]
  wav,
  [Description("image/vnd.wap.wbmp")]
  wbmp,
  [Description("application/vnd.wap.wbxml")]
  wbmxl,
  [Description("text/vnd.wap.wml")]
  wml,
  [Description("application/vnd.wap.wmlc")]
  wmlc,
  [Description("text/vnd.wap.wmlscript")]
  wmls,
  [Description("application/vnd.wap.wmlscriptc")]
  wmlsc,
  [Description("model/vrml")]
  wrl,
  [Description("image/x-xbitmap")]
  xbm,
  [Description("application/xhtml+xml")]
  xht,
  [Description("application/xhtml+xml")]
  xhtml,
  [Description("application/vnd.ms-excel")]
  xls,
  [Description("application/xml")]
  xml,
  [Description("image/x-xpixmap")]
  xpm,
  [Description("application/xml")]
  xsl,
  [Description("application/xslt+xml")]
  xslt,
  [Description("application/vnd.mozilla.xul+xml")]
  xul,
  [Description("image/x-xwindowdump")]
  xwd,
  [Description("chemical/x-xyz")]
  xyz,
  [Description("application/zip")]
  zip
}
```

Comment: I am trying to return a file from the controller. I am using exactly [this method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/dd492492.aspx) so using the exact content-type/mime-type makes also the client to behave correctly (like rendering the pdf, opening ms word, etc.)

Comment: Then surely you just need to ensure you pass the correct `content-disposition` header when sending the file to the client.

Comment: Just using the file extension is not particularly safe if you are worried about security.

Answer (score 115):

In .Net 4.5 you can use [`MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mimemapping.getmimemapping):

```
string contentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping("someFileName.pdf")
// contentType = "application/pdf"
```

[More information](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/02/14/getting-a-mime-type-from-a-file-extension-in-asp-net-4-5.aspx)

Comment: Be aware that this question is tagged asp.net and that this MimeMapping is an ASP.net extension (System.Web.MimeMapping)

Comment: Any idea how to achieve the opposite? Getting extension from MimeType?

Comment: @Jackie Many extensions can be represented by a single mime type so the reverse mapping won't always work.

Answer (score 8):

**.NET CORE** 
Using  Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles

```
var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
string contentType;
if(!provider.TryGetContentType(fileName, out contentType))
{
    contentType = "application/octet-stream";
}
```

Comment: This is correct answer for dotnet core era. But still wondering why they don't have some simplistic solution rather than "Try.." kind of method. Though it helped wout using installing any third party plugin etc. in a console application I am working on. Thanks.

Comment: This package is deprecated: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles/

Answer (score 7):

IDEA: put the formats and extensions data (http://www.feedforall.com/mime-types.htm) into an xml or into your project as dictionary, array or sth else for query and create a procedure for determine mimetype for extension.. i think keeping your data on xml document will be easier for modification after compiling

Comment: Is there any standard file where I can write all these mime types?

Comment: @Lorenzo: I took the liberty of translating that file into XML - http://pastebin.com/94ivivP4

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use stream

```
    public class urlmonMimeDetect
    {
        [DllImport(@"urlmon.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private extern static System.UInt32 FindMimeFromData(
            System.UInt32 pBC,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] System.String pwzUrl,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] byte[] pBuffer,
            System.UInt32 cbSize,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] System.String pwzMimeProposed,
            System.UInt32 dwMimeFlags,
            out System.UInt32 ppwzMimeOut,
            System.UInt32 dwReserverd
        );

        public static string GetMimeFromFile(Stream fs)
        {

            byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
            fs.Read(buffer, 0, 256);

            try
            {
                System.UInt32 mimetype;
                FindMimeFromData(0, null, buffer, 256, null, 0, out mimetype, 0);
                System.IntPtr mimeTypePtr = new IntPtr(mimetype);
                string mime = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(mimeTypePtr);
                Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(mimeTypePtr);
                return mime;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return "unknown/unknown";
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the file being uploaded to the MVC application?

```
public ActionResult FileUploader(HttpPostedFileBase upload)
{
  string mimeType=upload.ContentType;
}
```

There are a couple of caveats with this though.

It uses the browser supplied aka 'client supplied' mime type, if the users uploading items aren't authenticated or trusted, then this might not be a good idea.

Also IE doesn't always give standard Mime types for certain files, in particular PNGs (see [What is the difference between "image/png" and "image/x-png"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086374/what-is-the-difference-between-image-png-and-image-x-png)) which may or may not effect your application.

We just use a simple if statement to convert the IE png mime type (image/x-png), back to the more common one (image/png).

Comment: as you may read from the question I am trying to use it not for upload but for download indeed. I am using it in the context of the `Controller.File(...)` method call

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a linux/unix like system you can use the `file` command to determine the file type.

> There are three sets of tests, performed in this order: filesystem tests, magic number tests, and language tests. The first test that succeeds causes the file type to be printed.

If you're on a Windows machine it is common to use the file extension like you showed in your code.

Comment: On a web application I dont have any of these products installed on the server: word, excel, powerpoint, adobe, etc. so I suppose that no key are available in the registry but maybe I have to register types in the mime type list. How I can do?