# File upload not working in IE

Tags: php, file, upload

I just tested this simple php file upload script. Works in all browsers except IE :(

IE prints "FILETYPE NOT SUPPORTED" as defined inside code:

```
if (isset($_POST['add'])) {

  $order = $_POST['display_order'];
  $img = $HTTP_POST_FILES['imagefile']['name'];
  $url = $_POST['url'];

  // CONNECT TO DB
  mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
  @mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");


  $types = array('image/jpeg', 'image/gif', 'image/png', 'image/tiff', 'image/bmp', 'image/pjpeg');  
  $target_path = "media/";
  $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['imagefile']['name']); 

  if (in_array($_FILES['imagefile']['type'], $types)) {

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagefile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {

      mysql_query(
        "INSERT INTO slider_luxury
           (display_order, imagefile, url) 
         VALUES
           ('$order', '$img', '$url')"
      );

      header('Location: luxury_slider.php');

    } else {

      echo "There was an error uploading the slide, please try again!"; 

    }

  } else {

    echo "FILETYPE NOT SUPPORTED";

  }  

}
```

Comment: So add debug statements. Find out what condition is failing. Compare the input to that condition when you are using IE to when you are using something else.

Comment: try doing var_dump($_FILES); and see what you get

Comment: What are you actually doing with this data? You could probably accept all image types, so you could just check `strtolower(substr(ltrim($_FILES['imagefile']['type']),0,6)) == 'image/'`, but even then relying on the MIME type sent by the browser is asking for trouble - it doesn't really tell you anything as it could easily be spoofed. Also the browser will generate this largely from the file extension, which again cannot be relied upon. If you really want to check that the image is valid you would have to use something like [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php).

Comment: @wrongstars image/x-png? so the var_dump you posted doesn't even refer to the problem here?

Comment: The fact that you are getting that output in the var_dump($_FILES) statement means that the problem is not with the file data being sent by the web browser, if a problem were existing, then it would more likely be with the PHP code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that IE send the png with another MIME type than "image/png" which is what you are expecting. Try to add to your array of accepted values:

```
 image/x-png
```

Also see this [What is the difference between "image/png" and "image/x-png"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086374/what-is-the-difference-between-image-png-and-image-x-png).