# PNG files won't upload

Tags: php, upload, png

I have the following script that I use to upload pictures; This file works with every other file extension except for PNG files. Is there any reason?

This is my script;

```
// initialization
$result_final = "";
$counter = 0;

// List of our known photo types
$known_photo_types = array(
'image/pjpeg' => 'jpg',
'image/jpeg' => 'jpg',
'image/gif' => 'gif',
'image/bmp' => 'bmp',
'image/x-png' => 'png');
    
// GD Function Suffix List
$gd_function_suffix = array(
'image/pjpeg' => 'JPEG',
'image/jpeg' => 'JPEG',
'image/gif' => 'GIF',
'image/bmp' => 'WBMP',
'image/x-png' => 'PNG');

// Fetch the photo array sent by preupload.php
$photos_uploaded = $_FILES['photo_filename'];
// Fetch the photo caption array
$photo_caption = $_POST['photo_caption'];
while( $counter <= count($_FILES['photo_filename']['tmp_name']) ) 

    {
            if($photos_uploaded['size'][$counter] > 0)
            {
                    if(!array_key_exists($photos_uploaded['type'][$counter], $known_photo_types))
                    {
                            $result_final .= "File ".($counter+1)." is not a photo!<br />";
                    }else{
                    
                       mysql_query( "INSERT INTO database(`filename`, `caption`, `category`, `id`) VALUES('0', '".addslashes($caption[$counter])."', '".addslashes($_POST['category'])."', '".addslashes($_POST['id'])."')" );
                            $new_id = mysql_insert_id();
                            $filetype = $photos_uploaded['type'][$counter];
                            $extention = $known_photo_types[$filetype];
                            $filename = $new_id.".".$extention;

                            @mysql_query( "UPDATE database SET photo_filename='".addslashes($filename)."' WHERE photo_id='".addslashes($new_id)."'" );

// Store the orignal file
copy($photos_uploaded['tmp_name'][$counter], $images_dir2."/".$filename);

// Let's get the original image size                                
$size = GetImageSize( $images_dir2."/".$filename );

// .................................................................................
// Lets resize the image if its width is greater than 500 pixels
// Resized image settings
if ($size[0] > '1'){
        $Config_width_wide = 800; // width of wide image
        $Config_height_wide = 800; // height of wide image

        $Config_width_tall = 800; // width of tall image
        $Config_height_tall = 800; // height of tall image

// The Code
        if($size[0] > $size[1]){
            $image_width = $Config_width_wide;
            $image_height = (int)($Config_width_wide * $size[1] / $size[0]);

            if($image_height > $Config_height_wide){
                $image_height = $Config_height_wide;
                $image_width = (int)($Config_height_wide * $size[0] / $size[1]);
            }
        }else{
            $image_width = (int)($Config_height_tall * $size[0] / $size[1]);
            $image_height = $Config_height_tall;

            if($image_width > $Config_width_tall){
                $image_width = $Config_width_tall;
                $image_height = (int)($Config_width_tall * $size[1] / $size[0]);
            }
        }

// Build image with GD 2.x.x, you can use the other described methods too
$function_suffix = $gd_function_suffix[$filetype];
$function_to_read = "ImageCreateFrom".$function_suffix;
$function_to_write = "Image".$function_suffix;

// Read the source file
$source_handle = $function_to_read ( $images_dir2."/".$filename );

if($source_handle){
// Let's create a blank image for the image
$destination_handle = ImageCreateTrueColor ( $image_width, $image_height );

// Now we resize it
ImageCopyResampled( $destination_handle, $source_handle, 0, 0, 0, 0, $image_width, $image_height, $size[0], $size[1] );
}

// Store the orignal file
copy($photos_uploaded['tmp_name'][$counter], $images_dir2."/".$filename);
 
// Let's save the image
if ($extension == 'png') {
$function_to_write( $destination_handle, $images_dir2."/".$filename, 9 );
} else {
$function_to_write( $destination_handle, $images_dir2."/".$filename, 90 ); 
}
ImageDestroy($destination_handle );
        
                    }

                }
            }
        $counter++;
    }   
} else exit('<p>Error: ' .
    mysql_error() . '</p>');
```

Thats my code and everything works fine when I upload a jpeg or gif file but when I upload a png file, it doesn't work. I don't get no error neither. Please, what could be the error?

Comment: Silly question, but is that the right MIME type for PNG?

Comment: guess it wasn't. Just got it corrected. The right one is image/png thanxx @andrewsi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merely change it to:

```
image/png
```

Comment: or maybe add new one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086374/what-is-the-difference-between-image-png-and-image-x-png

Answer (score 1):

png is an officially recognized mime type, it should be just `image/png`. the `x-` prefix is for experimental/unofficial types. You could trivially verify what you're getting with `var_dump($_FILES)`.

Your upload handling code also needs updates. You do not check for successful uploads, and simply assume they succeeded. NEVER assume success.

```
if($_FILES['photo_filename']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
  die("Upload failed with error code " . $_FILES['photo_filename']['error']);
}
```

`addslashes()` is utterly useless pointless garbage. It does **NOTHING** to protect you against sql injection attacks. If you insist on continuing to use the deprecated mysql_*() functions, then at least use the proper `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

Comment: wow thanx @Marc B, preciate your comments. Am relatively new to this coding thing so truly appreciate all the suggestions and will implement them immediately into my codings. I presume the updates should come right after the $counter++