# output image via php problems

Tags: php, image, readfile

I am aware that this is probably a very trivial problem which I just can't seem to get right although I have spent the last few hours crawling the web..

I have a file image_get.php which is supposed to display an image file "keepcalm.png" that is located in the same directory as the php file.

I am using a class to handle all the image related actions.

image_get.php

```
<?php
   include "classes/image.class.php"; 
   include "classes/database.class.php";
   $database_sso = new database('SSO'); //will be needed later and is dummy for now
   $testimage = new image($database_sso, "1"); //parameters are dummy for now
   $testimage->show_image();
?>
```

image.class.php

```
<?php

class image{
   private $database_image;     //Image Database containing all images
   private $imageid;            //ID of Image in Database
   private $filepath;           //Path to image file


//PUBLIC FUNCTIONS  
   public function __construct($database, $imageid){
     $this->database_image = $database;     //Right now this is just a placeholder
     $this->imageid = $imageid;         //Right now this is just a placeholder

   }

    public function show_image(){

    $remoteImage = $this->get_local_link_from_id($this->imageid);  // Right now this returns "keepcalm.png"

    header('Content-Type: image/x-png')
    $returnstring = readfile($remoteImage);

}
 //PRIVATE FUNCTIONS
private function get_local_link_from_id($imageid){

    $local_link = "keepcalm.png"; //dummy for now
    return $local_link;
}


}



?>
```

The output I get is complet gibberish as can be seen here -> http://niederrad.no-ip.org/portal/image_get.php

What am I missing?
I have tried lots of iterations of the above and am completely clueless as to how I should proceed..

Comment: Your header with content-type is not sent to browser. This is function, not a string!! `header('Content-Type: image/x-png')`. Should be, at least, `$returnstring = readfile($remoteImage); header('Content-Type: image/x-png');`

Comment: How would you send it?

$returnstring = header('Content-Type: image/x-png').readfile($remoteImage);
  
return $returnstring;

that won't work...

Comment: I wrote it! `$returnstring = readfile($remoteImage); header('Content-Type: image/x-png');` You should run the function and it will generate http response headers, not return it.

Comment: Hm. If I do it in that order I get a "headers already sent" error.

If I put the header('Content-Type: image/x-png'); first I get only an empty image icon..

see
http://niederrad.no-ip.org/portal/image_get.php

Comment: It means that your code is a mess, read this (there should be no output to the browser before the headers are sent) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php  And are you going to return `$returnstring` from function??? If you do not return the content of the file or not send it to browser from within the function - it will not be shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was with BOM which I find very strange as I was sure I had checked to not encode with BOM...

[How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

A very good suggestion from Cheery.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function show_image() {

    // this returns "keepcalm.png"
    $remoteImage = $this->get_local_link_from_id($this->imageid);

    // Set Header
    header("Content-Type: image/png"); // More info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2086406/2332336

    // Output the contents of image
    readfile($remoteImage);
    exit;
}
```

If this doesn't work for you, it means PHP is not able to locate the local image `keepcalm.png`
Possibly because it doesn't exist here: `http://niederrad.no-ip.org/portal/keepcalm.png` (i.e. from the script (`image_get.php`) execution location `http://niederrad.no-ip.org/portal/`)

If this is the case, you might have to tell your `readfile()` command where the image is located on your server. By that I mean specify the absolute path to file (on linux server `/home/USERNAME/public_html/images/` for example)

If the image is on a remote server (as your variable name suggests), then your code should look like this:

```
    // Output the contents of image
    exit(file_get_contents('http://remote-site.com/path/to/'. $remoteImage));
```

Assuming your PHP config has `allow_url_fopen` set to true.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. 
Unfortunately your suggestion is the first thing I initially tried and the file is here http://niederrad.no-ip.org/portal/keepcalm.png -> please try the URL.

Comment: I have checked the file location with file_exists() and that is not the problem..

Comment: Alexander (below) makes a good point about `BOM` on the file. Have you tried opening the file in `Notepad++` save it using `Encoding -> Encode in ANSI` and then save the file and try again?